# Change font style to richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I want change font style in RichTextBox sp. 
I working in WPF.

```
sp.FontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
```

Error say: `System.Windows.FontStyle' does not contain a definition for 'Bold'` 
I don't know, how to change, if this start working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Bold in **FontWeight**-property:

```
sp.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

Same in WinForms:

```
sp.Font = new Font(sp.Font.Name, sp.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
```